# Inequality $\Vert f(x)\Vert\leq\frac{1}{2}\Vert x\Vert^2$

Tags: analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ open and connected with $0 \in U$

If $f\in C^2(U;\mathbb{R}^m)$ with $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$ and ($\Vert \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}(x)\Vert\leq\Vert u\Vert \Vert v\Vert$ or $\Vert f'(x)\Vert\ \leq \Vert x\Vert$ ), for all $x\in U$ and for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Show that:

$$\Vert f(x)\Vert\leq\frac{1}{2}\Vert x\Vert^2 \quad \forall x\in U$$

My attempt:

Such that $f$ is continuous and connected in $U$ I can use Inequality of mean value and, $\forall x,y \in U$  $$ \Vert f(y)-f(x) \Vert\leq\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\Vert f'(x+th) \Vert \Vert y-x\Vert \quad \mbox{with } y=x+h$$
If $y=0$ :  $\Vert f(x) \Vert\leq\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\Vert f'(x(1-t)) \Vert \Vert x\Vert$

By the hypothesis: $\Vert f(x) \Vert\leq\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\Vert x(1-t) \Vert \Vert x\Vert=\Vert x\Vert^2sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}(1-t)=\Vert x\Vert^2$

But I'm missing $1/2$ and I do not know in the case of $\Vert \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}(x)\Vert\leq\Vert u\Vert \Vert v\Vert$. Help please.